# Error in printing the div content

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

Hi guys i am using this jQuery function for printing the div contents.
1st time it show/print the empty page. but 2nd time it works .
it show the div content's in `console.log()` but not print these contents.

i am trying to find out the issue but stuck on it. please help

thanks in advance .

```
jQuery.fn.LBCprint = function()
{
    var jStyleDiv = '';
    var strFrameName = ("printer-" + (new Date()).getTime());
    var jFrame = $("<iframe name='"+strFrameName+"'>");
    jFrame.css("width", "1px").css("height", "1px").css("position", "absolute").css("left", "-9999px").appendTo($("body:first"));

    // Get a FRAMES reference to the new frame.
    var objFrame = window.frames[strFrameName];

    // Get a reference to the DOM in the new frame.
    var objDoc = objFrame.document;

    jStyleDiv = $("<div>").append(
        $("style").clone()
    );

    objDoc.open();
    objDoc.write("<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd\">");
    objDoc.write("<html>");
    objDoc.write("<head>");
    objDoc.write("<title>");
    objDoc.write(document.title);
    objDoc.write("</title>");
    objDoc.write("<link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" href=\"https://www.abc.com/n/css/main_style_print.css\" />");
    objDoc.write("<link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" href=\"https://www.abc.com/n/css/dashboard.css\" />");
    objDoc.write("<link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" href=\"https://www.abc.com/assets/css/pagination.css\" />");
    objDoc.write("</head>");
    objDoc.write("<body>");
    objDoc.write(jStyleDiv.html());
    objDoc.write(this.html());
    objDoc.write("</body>");
    objDoc.write("</html>");
    objDoc.close();

    // Print the document.
    objFrame.focus();
    objFrame.print();

    jStyleDiv = '';

    setTimeout(function(){
        jFrame.remove();
    }, (10000));
}
```

Comment: **Do not** use `document.write`, it strangely enough overwrites the document.

Comment: @adeneo what is the alternative ?? plz

Comment: You're using jQuery, read the documentation ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works fine for me after replacing

```
// Print the document.
objFrame.focus();
objFrame.print();
```

with

```
// Print the document.
objFrame.onload = function(){
    objFrame.focus();
    objFrame.print();
    jFrame.remove();
};
```

I guess your frame sometimes isn't rendered at printing.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

```
    html = "<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd\">";
    html += "<html>";
    html += "<head>";
    html += "<title>";
    html += document.title;
    html += "</title>";
    html += "<link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" href=\"https://www.abc.com/n/css/main_style_print.css\" />";
    html += "<link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" href=\"https://www.abc.com/n/css/dashboard.css\" />";
    html += "<link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" href=\"https://www.abc.com/assets/css/pagination.css\" />";
    html += "</head>";
    html += "<body>";
    html += jStyleDiv.html();
    html += this.html();
    html += "</body>";
    html += "</html>";

    objDoc.open();
    objDoc.write(html);
    objDoc.close();
```

Comment: This code would redefined the ```html``` variable at every line. By the end of this you are just essentially calling ```objDoc.write('</html>');```

Answer (score 0):

I made it this simple way and You can use $ instead of jQuery to make all simple so that no conflict happens. I just print body content.

```
$.fn.LBCprint = function()
{
 var jStyleDiv = '';
 var strFrameName = ("printer-" + (new Date()).getTime());
 var jFrame = $("<iframe name='"+strFrameName+"'>");
 jFrame.css("width", "1px").css("height", "1px").css("position", 
 "absolute").css("left", "-9999px").appendTo($("body:first"));

 // Get a FRAMES reference to the new frame.
 var objFrame = window.frames[strFrameName];

 // Get a reference to the DOM in the new frame.
 var objDoc = objFrame.document;

 jStyleDiv = $("<div>").append(
    $("style").clone()
 );

objDoc.open();
objDoc.write("<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN\"  
              \"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd\">");
objDoc.write("<html>");
objDoc.write("<head>");
objDoc.write("<title>");
objDoc.write(document.title);
objDoc.write("</title>");
objDoc.write("<link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" href=\"https://www.abc.com
              /n/css/main_style_print.css\" />");
objDoc.write("<link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" href=\"https://www.abc.com
             /n/css/dashboard.css\" />");
objDoc.write("<link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" href=\"https://www.abc.com
              /assets/css/pagination.css\" />");
objDoc.write("</head>");
objDoc.write("<body>");
objDoc.write(jStyleDiv.html());
objDoc.write(document.body.innerHTML);
objDoc.write("</body>");
objDoc.write("</html>");
objDoc.close();

// Print the document.
objFrame.focus();
objFrame.print();

jStyleDiv = '';

setTimeout(function(){
    jFrame.remove();
}, (10000));
}
```

Here is [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/salahuddin112/wn5x7d65/1/)